# facebook JSOn API question

Tags: json, facebook, api, comments

I am using JSON GRAPH API for facebook to retrieve all the post from a particular group. I can access all the post without authentication. However the problem I have is, if a particular post has more comments (like 10) then JSON outputs shows only  3 comments(not all 10). However the "Key" "Count" in JSON output gives the value as 10(meaning 10 comments for the post) but displays only 3. How to resolve this problem.

ANy help is greatly appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 1):

In that json data set there is a a key named 'paging' that gives you the next and previous sets ('next' and 'previous' respectively). You can use those urls to traverse all comments.

See the section named 'Paging' in the docs here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api?ref=mf  for more stuff (like limits and time queries)

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the JSOn output I don't see a paging key for comments. FYI I am trying to access the group information which is available public.  Here is the link I am using http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Comment: the paging is in the feed of the group, not the base of the group.